# How to get the tile number (x y z) a marker is placed on?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need to get the tile number (x, y, z) for a clicked marker using the Google Maps API v3.

There is little documentation available which discusses this. How would I even start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Get the marker lat lng which is a property of to the marker click event object.
2. Use the map projection (`map.getProjection()`) to convert to world coordinates (also known as point plane).
3. Using the current map zoom level (which is your 'z' coordinate), calculate the pixel coordinates from the world coordinates:
   `pixelCoordinateX = parseInt(worldCoordinateX * Math.pow(2, zoom), 10)`. Same concept for the 'y' coordinate.
4. Divide the pixelCoordinate by the tile size (256) and take the integer portion. This is the tile number.
   `x = parseInt(pixelCoordinateX / 256, 10)`.

See the [Map Types concepts in the Google Maps API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#MapCoordinates).

Comment: I edited the question because I thought is was worthwhile and did not agree with it being closed. I wanted to see it reopened because figuring out the tile from a given lat lng isn't straightforward. Frankly I think it was closed because you asked two different but similar questions back to back.