# How can i place markers by tile number instead Lat Lng

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to place markers on map by **tile number** instead **Lat, Lng** coordinate. Is it possible?

Comment: -1 instead of bombing us with questions wait a moment till you get an answer and start some own investigations.

Comment: no need explanation for -1

Comment: of course there is a need for it, otherwise you wouldn't have asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. You must first convert tile number to lat lng. Reverse the directions in the [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547940/how-to-get-tile-x-y-z-info-of-marker-when-clicked-it#14548229).